# Execute system command with php return code 77

Tags: php, libreoffice, shell-exec

I am trying to convert word document to pdf using libreoffice. The command works fine in terminal but in controller of my application written in php using `shell_exec()` or `exec()` it doesn't work. `exec()`'s return_var is 77 and I think it means :

> Bad file descriptor

Any suggestions would be highly appretiated.

Comment: Exit code 77 is “permission denied”. Your server process is not allowed to execute said binary.

Comment: So what is the workaround?

Comment: This is too broad. And purely Linux related. Should rather be posted on ServerFault? I don't know any of your server specifics to be able to help you sorry. There are lots of posts here already why single binary works in the bash, but not via the PHP's exec and the answer is simple: different environment.

Comment: Thanks man. This really helped.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error code and by adding "2>&1" at the end of command line got detailed error:

(process:24718): dconf-CRITICAL **: 10:11:59.019: unable to create directory '/var/www/.cache/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

Hope this will help someone to get detailed error and also possibility to find a solution.

Example code:

```
exec('/usr/bin/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf ' . BASEPATH . 'test.docx 2>&1', $v_output, $l_return);
var_dump($v_output);
var_dump($l_return);
```

Answer (score 1):

I add this command option to fixed it:

```
 -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/test
```

My code is:

```
  $command = "{$bin} -env:UserInstallation=file:///tmp/test --headless --convert-to pdf:writer_pdf_Export --outdir  '{$pdfTmpDir}' '{$path}' 2>&1";
  exec($command, $output, $code);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ì got the same error and fixed it with :
`$command = HOME=/tmp/ shellCommand ....`